# Background proccess call api in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem in my ionic apps, it must update data from database server to sqlite every 30 minutes 
I need an example about how to make a job scheduller that run every 30 minutes

Is jobscheduller still works even if I use IOS?

Comment: Could you provide any source of the problem. Maybe a piece of code.

Comment: Sorry julio, i no have idea for that source code, if you ever made that things can you share me referances, and how about my second question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the background mode plugin, [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/) you can find the plugin

After that you have finished with the installation of the plugin you can enable the background mode, it means that the app don't will die until you disable the background mode again.

**Disclaimer: this solution can be expensive in terms of battery usage**

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {BackgroundMode} from '@ionic-native/background-mode';

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

   constructor(private plt: Platform, private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode) {
      this.plt.ready().then(() => {
         this.backgroundMode.enable();
         // start an interval with a delay of 30 min
         setInterval(() => {
            console.log('background on'):
         }, 30 * 60000);
      });
   }
}
```

This is just a sample code, remember to handle how you will turn off the background mode and dispose the interval.

Comment: Thanks diego, is it still work on ios device, and is it still works even i foce close the application?

Comment: If you force the app to be closed it won't work, it just will prevent the common behavior of the app.

Comment: How about, if i not open the app is still work? I think it deferent case from close the app isn't it?

Comment: Background plugin would be a good solution, but you have to read [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#store-compliance) first.

Comment: @BennyChan too broad your comment and you didn't provide new information, next time that you down vote an answer provide valuable information about why you did that.